# Is there a way to make a link that goes to a row/cell from a table?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a word that when clicked (like a link) it will go to a specific row on a table, all on the same page. I have a table with this format:

```
<div id="table1">
<table width='100%' id = 'table1'>
    <tr>
        <th><b>Coluna1:</b></th>
        <th><b>Coluna2:</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Word1</td>
        <td>Text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Word2</td>
        <td>Text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Word3</td>
        <td>Word3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Give the row or cell an ID and link to it e.g. `<a href="#rowID">link</a>`

Comment: Also, you can't have two equal `id`s in different elements.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that the ids where equals. And the id for the cell worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by setting `id`s for each row/cell you want to go to and linking to `#<id>`.

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: yellow; }
  to { background-color: #0000; }
}

:target {
  animation: highlight 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<p>Go to</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#word1">Word1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text1">Text1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#row1">Row1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#text2">Text2</a></li>
</ul>

<table width='100%' id ="table1">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Coluna1:</b></th>
        <th><b>Coluna2:</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="word1">Word1</td>
        <td id="text1">Text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td id="word2">Word2</td>
        <td id="text2">Text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Word3</td>
        <td>Word3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor links. For example:

```
<div id="table1">
<table width='100%' id = 'table1'>
    <tr>
        <th><b>Coluna1:</b></th>
        <th><b>Coluna2:</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#word1'>Word1</a></td>
        <td>Text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#word2'>Word2</a></td>
        <td>Text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='#word3'>Word3</a></td>
        <td>Word3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then link to your page like: https://www.example.com/index.html#word1

Replace what comes after the "#" character with whatever anchor tag you want to link to.